# Relative clause or separate phrases?

Tags: sentence, relative-clauses

I'm wondering if the following:

> 話そうよ星空に二人の夢

Is a relative clause with 話そうよ preceding the rest of the line or two separate sentences? The part that's throwing me off is the よ particle. Does it emphasize the 'Let's talk' before it, or is it an interjection?

Comment: There’s no relative clause here.

Comment: This is inversion, volitionals almost never form relative clauses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you guess, the particle [よ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%88/#jn-226011) is in the category 終助詞, which literally means 'ending particle'. So the sentence ends at 話そうよ.

It is an inverted form as suggested in a comment. The regular order would be

- 星空に二人の夢(を)話そうよ
- 二人の夢(を)星空に話そうよ

meaning *Let's talk the dream of us two to the starry sky*.

Comment: So 不安だった未来は優しく叶ったね夕暮れの二人の夢 would be the same case with the particle ね? With the usual order being 夕暮れの二人の夢不安だった未来は優しく叶ったね, although it's sometimes used mid-sentence?

Comment: @A.T.A. Since nothing is 'missing' in 不安だった未来は優しく叶ったね, just inversing the whole thing shouldn't be correct. One possibility is: 不安だった未来は優しく、夕暮れの二人の夢(は/が)叶ったね.

Comment: Perhaps the particle ね represents where to put a comma or an ellipsis?